# Source of the quotation "A hungry stomach …"

Tags: phrase-origin

I've seen a quote saying "A hungry stomach, an empty pocket and a broken heart can teach the best lessons of life."

Does anyone know who said this, or where it was taken from?

Depending on the internet source you check, it could be [Robin Williams](https://m.facebook.com/108558503877929/photos/pb.108558503877929.-2207520000../470489704351472/?type=3&eid=ARDflUi6FC7gcJBQaPQwCF2OEFrRse9yZYPWMT8qZfQKJ32Cv6AsmFhr4MmbfYfi8_H1ItwBg0UNvLGd), [Abdul Sattar Edhi](https://www.chetanbro.com/2019/12/chetanbro-quotes-38.html), or someone else entirely. None of the sources gives a specific citation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reasonably close match that a Google Books search returns for the phrase you ask about is from Tehmina Durrani, [*Abdul Sattar Edhi: An Autobiography: A Mirror to the Blind*](https://books.google.com/books?id=hwHlAAAAMAAJ&q=stomach+%22empty+pocket%22+%22broken+heart%22&dq=stomach+%22empty+pocket%22+%22broken+heart%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBgrP7xovSAhXJrVQKHcxjBgAQ6AEIGjAA) (1996) [snippet view]:

> "... If she is searching for me, she will find me in a hungry stomach, in a broken heart, an empty pocket and at the doorstep of a shack."

Because this is a snippet view of the source text, it is impossible to identify the original source and to infer the full significance of the quoted language, but the paragraph of text following the quoted sentence indicates that the (unidentified) speaker's words are being cited in regard to the impending breakup of the marriage of Abdul Sattar Edhi's daughter. So the speaker seems to be equating the loss of a close relationship with elemental suffering such as hunger, poverty, and heartbreak. I suppose that such suffering could be interpreted as "teach[ing] the best lessons in life."